# Is my proxy, which is a tor relay, my guard/entry-node?

Tags: guard

If I set my own relay (running in my LAN) as the SOCKS proxy (e.g. in my browser), does this mean this relay automatically functions as the guard/entry-relay?

edited for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you relay has been upgraded to a guard node (this takes time to gain the trust of the network, enough bandwidth, speed, etc.) then it is possible that your relay *could* be your guard but it's not guaranteed that it will be.

Comment: you again ;-) So, if I understand correctly, the route in this case is:
Alice-proxy-guard-middle-exit-Bob? Wouldn't it be better if I could use my own relay as my guard node? 1) Since I own it, I trust it. 2) Network load and number of hops would be reduced.

Comment: The manual has some settings on how to limit which guard nodes you get if you are running your own private Tor network. I just don't see where there is functionality specifically for that in normal Tor.